# Wildfly 10 constantly loses connection to Postgres datasource

Tags: java, database, postgresql, jboss, wildfly

I´ve succesfully set up a Postgres datasource on Wildfly 10.1 final. The application that uses the datasource is still under development and therefore not really in use yet.

Wildfly and postgres each are running in their own VM but on the same host machine.

About once a day, the connection apparently gets lost, and only a restart of wildfly will suffice to re-establish it.

In wildfly´s server.log I can´t find any message related to my datasource. Here is the datasource configuration from standalone.xml

```
           <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/JMPostgres" pool-name="PostgresDS" enabled="true" use-ccm="false">
                <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://10.66.1.102:5432/jm10</connection-url>
                <driver-class>org.postgresql.Driver</driver-class>
                <driver>postgresql-42.1.4.jar</driver>
                <pool>
                    <min-pool-size>5</min-pool-size>
                    <initial-pool-size>5</initial-pool-size>
                    <max-pool-size>50</max-pool-size>
                    <prefill>true</prefill>
                </pool>
                <security>
                    <user-name>jm10</user-name>
                    <password>Ba4aeng$eeth0iog.ee2zohB</password>
                </security>
                <validation>
                    <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.postgres.PostgreSQLValidConnectionChecker"/>
                    <check-valid-connection-sql>SELECT 1 FROM DUAL;</check-valid-connection-sql>
                    <validate-on-match>true</validate-on-match>
                    <background-validation>true</background-validation>
                    <background-validation-millis>60000</background-validation-millis>
                    <stale-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.postgres.StaleConnectionChecker"/>
                    <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.postgres.PostgreSQLExceptionSorter"/>
                </validation>
                <timeout>
                    <allocation-retry>5</allocation-retry>
                    <allocation-retry-wait-millis>10000</allocation-retry-wait-millis>
                </timeout>
            </datasource>
```

Comment: Remove the `check-valid-connection-sql` element. This is for Oracle and will fail on PostgreSQL.

Comment: Or replace it with `SELECT 1`.

Comment: I´ve added `check-valid-connection-sql` later, so it can´t be the cause for the problem, but I'll change it to SELECT 1

Comment: I've seen this sort of thing before when there is a firewall device between the application server and the database. These things tend to not like long lived connections and they just stop handling network traffic without formally dropping the TCP connection. Therefore, neither the app-server or the database know that the connection is no longer working.

Comment: @SteveC: But shouldn´t wildfly re-connect on the next database request in that case? I thought this is what the validator is good for.